# How can validate if the folder is already exists?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dropbox, dropzone.js

Hi im trying to validate if the file is already exists before uploading to dropbox

**this is my js using dropzone/dropbox**

```
  for (var i = 0, file_name; file_name = dropzone.files[i]; i++) {
         $.ajax({
           url: url,
           type: 'POST',
           data: file_name,
           processData: false,
           contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
           headers: {
           "Authorization": "ACCESSTOKEN",
           "Dropbox-API-Arg": '{"path": "/'+file_name.name+'", "mode": "add","autorename": true,"mute": false}'
           },

           success: function (data){

           console.log(data);


           }

          })
       }
```

Comment: You can not check file/folder availability before the upload it. However, if you want to check, you should create another ajax post to check is exists or not.

Comment: Where should I put the other ajax?

Comment: yes, before upload. check it exists or not. then upload it. method like preupload.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a file or folder already exists at a particular path first by calling [/2/files/get_metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_metadata).

However, note that there's a race condition with that, in that something can be added from elsewhere in between your calls to [/2/files/get_metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_metadata) and [/2/files/upload](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload).

Instead, you can use the `mode` options on [/2/files/upload](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload) to control what should happen if there is already something at the path you're trying to upload to.